# DB2 SQL Replication - pthread quiesce issue (abend S422)

Tags: db2, replication

We are in the process of configuring the IBM SQL Replication tool for z/OS DB2. When I submit the APPLY job, its getting an abend of S422, with the below error message. Per the below error message, the APPLY job is unable to create a process 50397492, due to a pthread quiesce status.

```
14.28.12 JOB00271  ASN0600I  "Apply" : "" : "Initial" : Program         
"apply 11.4.0 (APAR ph49755, ASNRBASE APAR ph49755)" is starting.
14.28.12 JOB00271  BPXP011I THREAD 2041880000000001, IN PROCESS 50397492, WAS  598
598             TERMINATED DUE TO A PTHREAD QUIESCE OF TYPE 2.
14.28.12 JOB00271  IEA848I NO DUMP WAS PRODUCED FOR THIS ABEND, DUE TO SYSTEM OR INSTALLATION REQUEST
14.28.12 JOB00271  BPXP011I THREAD 2041F80000000002, IN PROCESS 50397492, WAS  601
601             TERMINATED DUE TO A PTHREAD QUIESCE OF TYPE 2.
14.28.12 JOB00271  BPXP011I THREAD 2040180000000000, IN PROCESS 50397492, WAS  602
602             TERMINATED DUE TO A PTHREAD QUIESCE OF TYPE 2.
14.28.14 JOB00271  IEF450I ASNAPP15 APPLY1 - ABEND=S422 U0000 REASON=000001A0
```

My question is, how to reset / cleanup this quiesce status. I'm sure there should be an easy way or a simple command to clean up this status. Are there any z/OS USS commands OR any procedure to do it thru the SQL replicator tool (DB2).

I searched all over(manuals internet etc.), but its like looking for a needle in a haystack.
I tried shutting down and restarting the DB2
I tried to run it with the separate new apply qualifier with a different set of tables etc. But none is working out.

Thanks,
Matt.